# When repairing package catalog: Failed to remove essential system package

Tags: 12.04

I recently made the mistake of trying to install a newer version of libattr1 from Trusty on my Precise installation so I could use Trusty's newer CMake(bad idea, I know). Halfway through the installation, it failed with an error. Now, the Software Center wants me to repair the package catalog. When I try, however, I get this:

[image: Failed to remove essential system package: Package libacl1:i386 cannot be removed]

Apt-get gives a slightly more descriptive error when I try to install something:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libattr1 : Breaks: libattr1:i386 (!= 1:2.4.46-8ubuntu2) but 1:2.4.46-5ubuntu1 is installed
 libattr1:i386 : Breaks: libattr1 (!= 1:2.4.46-5ubuntu1) but 1:2.4.46-8ubuntu2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Seems to be a circular dependency issue or something. When I run `sudo apt-get install -f`, this appears:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  bluez-alsa:i386 libsdl-ttf2.0-0:i386 libgconf-2-4:i386 libstdc++5:i386
  libgail18:i386 libqt4-qt3support:i386 libcupsimage2:i386 libnss3:i386
  gtk2-engines:i386 libgudev-1.0-0:i386 libcairo-gobject2:i386
  libavc1394-0:i386 libaio1:i386 odbcinst1debian2:i386 libqt4-test:i386
  libqt4-designer:i386 libsdl-mixer1.2:i386 libcap2:i386 libproxy1:i386
  ibus-gtk:i386 libdbus-glib-1-2:i386 libtdb1:i386 libspeex1:i386
  libibus-1.0-0:i386 libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 libcanberra0:i386
  gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 libwavpack1:i386 libqt4-opengl:i386
  libsoup-gnome2.4-1:i386 gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:i386 libiec61883-0:i386
  libsdl-image1.2:i386 libxaw7:i386 libgdbm3:i386 libesd0:i386 libmikmod2:i386
  libpulse-mainloop-glib0:i386 libaa1:i386 libao4:i386 pax libxmu6:i386
  libcanberra-gtk0:i386 libvorbisfile3:i386 libqt4-svg:i386
  libgail-common:i386 libraw1394-11:i386 libnspr4:i386 libshout3:i386
  libdv4:i386 rpm librpmbuild2 gstreamer0.10-x:i386 libsdl-net1.2:i386
  libgnome-keyring0:i386 libxtst6:i386 gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386
  libtag1c2a:i386 libssl0.9.8:i386 libmad0:i386 gtk2-engines-oxygen:i386
  lib32z1 xaw3dg:i386 librpmsign0 libpulsedsp:i386 libodbc1:i386
  libqt4-scripttools:i386 lsb-core libxp6:i386 alien libxmlrpc-core-c3
  ncurses-term icc-profiles-free glib-networking:i386 libsoup2.4-1:i386
  libtag1-vanilla:i386 libaudiofile1:i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  google-earth-stable ia32-libs ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 libacl1:i386
  libattr1:i386 softmaker-freeoffice
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 6 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 484 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

The thought of removing all those packages that seem critical freaks me out. What should I do? I don't even dare restart my computer now.

Comment: Similar to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118534/libssl1-0-0-wont-let-me-install-anything) issue. Also, apt is saying that all those packages are not required, not that they will be removed. The list of packages being removed are the 6 packages near the bottom of the output. That big list of packages are declared as not necessary because those are i386 packages (I'm assuming you have an amd64 system), and if you have no i386 applications, you probably won't need i386 packages.

Comment: The two applications you'll be losing in `apt-get install -f` are Google Earth (`google-earth-stable`) and something freeoffice? (`softmaker-freeoffice`).

Comment: @saiarcot895: But I DO have i386 applications!

Comment: I should have mentioned that the big list is assuming you do go ahead with the remove. Google Earth is i386, I think; don't know about the other application.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes if everything is broken, this command help.

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: I get this error: http://pastebin.com/t301ZTQR

Comment: That's a private paste. Others can't see private pastes. Also, see my comments above.

Comment: It should work now. I had meant to select "unlisted".

Comment: Not sure, but try uninstall those packages,..

Comment: Yes, either uninstalling one of the two packages will fix it, but you will lose other packages. Instead, you can tell apt to install the same version of the amd64 and i386 packages. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118534/libssl1-0-0-wont-let-me-install-anything) question

Answer (score 1):

Solved! I checked the [answer pointed out in the comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118534/libssl1-0-0-wont-let-me-install-anything) and ended up doing this:

```
sudo mv /usr/share/doc/libattr1/changelog.Debian.gz # /usr/share/doc/libattr1/changelog.Debian.gz.old
# the above was because apt-get was complaining about files not being the same
sudo apt-get install -f libattr1=1:2.4.46-5ubuntu1
```